# Achieve simple "payment transaction" in MYSQL (or any rdbms)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I basically want to efficiently check if account has enough balance before deduct value from it. Let's say I have the following schema

| account_id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100 |
| b | 50 |

I want to achieve the following logic

```
If account_balance < amount_to_charge:
   return False
else:
   udpate account_balcne = account_balance - amount_to_charge
   return True
```

It's important to get the boolean value back.

So using an example, if my charge amount is 100 to account a and b above. Assume I have a magic SQL function

- charge(a, 100) -> True

  - balance of account a updated to 0
  - I get true back
- chrage(b, 100) -> False

  - balance not updated
  - i get false back

How might one achieve this in SQL, ideally in one round trip?

EDIT:
I know how to do a conditional update by doing

```
update set account_balance = account_balance - x where accoutn_balance > x and account_id = 123
```

However, how might one also get a boolean value?

Comment: Why do expect true for charge(a,100), but false for charge(b,50)? Is this a typo? According to your sample data, the result value should be the same for these two examples.

Comment: @JonasMetzler good catch. updated

Answer (score 1):

1. Add CHECK constraint which checks that the balance value is not negative:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD CHECK (balance >= 0);
```

2. Perform the transaction as solid statement:

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET balance = CASE account_id WHEN @sender_id   THEN balance - @transfer
                              WHEN @receiver_id THEN balance + @transfer
                              ELSE balance
                              END
WHERE account_id IN (@sender_id, @receiver_id);
```

The whole transfer will either be performed successfully (and both accounts will be updated) or will produce an error 3819 (and none account will be updated).

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9126c9a837bf5b9549a61c056aaf7275)

Answer (score 1):

First I want to say that creating a function for such things is really no good way. It would be much better to just create a constraint (see also the answer by Akina).
But anyway, to answer your question: You can create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION yourfunction
(account VARCHAR(100), 
amount_to_charge DECIMAL
)RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
DECLARE account_balance DECIMAL;
SELECT balance INTO account_balance FROM yourtable
WHERE account_id = account;
IF account_balance < amount_to_charge THEN
RETURN (FALSE);
ELSE
UPDATE yourtable SET balance = account_balance - amount_to_charge 
WHERE account_id = account;
RETURN (TRUE);
END IF;
END
```

I created an example here which shows this is working correctly: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb6c75ef2411069863fd44cf0aba3e09)

Please note there is no "real" boolean in MYSQL, so this function will return 0 or 1. You have to convert it to true or false later on if necessary.

Comment: *this function will return 0 or 1. You have to convert it to true or false later on if necessary.* In MySQL `TRUE` is an alias of `1` and `FALSE` is an alias of `0`, none convertion needed.

Comment: Yes, therefore I wrote "if necessary". Likely, it will not be required to convert it later on, but I don't know where the OP would like to use this function and what he wants to do with its return value.

Comment: I mean that the convertion needed on the MySQL side never. But on the client side the convertion is needed always - MySQL never returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` but always 0 or 1.